Flutter my first app not running on virtual device
I try run my flutter project (VSCode) with Virtual device (android studio)
after 30 minutes I got after i stop running :
enter image description here
my flutter doctor :
enter image description here
my java jdk :
enter image description here
my git :
enter image description here
no thing to do it since 3 days i am trying to solve the issues which i faced
Any one can help ???

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors


Wipe Emulator Data:

Open Android Studio > AVD Manager > Select your device > Wipe Data.


Clean Flutter Project:

Run flutter clean in your project directory.


Rebuild and Run:

Run flutter pub get and flutter run.



This should help resolve the issues you're facing.
Happy coding :)
